# Detect Form.Icon change in .NET

Tags: .net, winforms, forms, icons

I'm trying to detect when a Form's Icon property is modified.
Currently I override the WndProc and handles the WM_SETICON message to do this.

This is intrusive and I would prefer a non-intrusive method.
I guess I could do some good old Win32 SetWindowLong to specifiy a new WndProc but I've heard that Forms can recreate the Win32 window behind the scenes when changing properties and if that's true this might be tricky to handle.

My second more important problem is that setting the Icon property on a non-visible window doesn't send the WM_SETICON message (until the Form becomes visible).

I would much appreciate any more insights into how this could be achieved.
It's a shame that the Form class doesn't implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface...

/Dosh

Comment: How does this property get changed? Through your own managed code?

Comment: Currently I do it my self (since all form needs to be inherited from my form with the overridden WndProc), so yes I could find all places that changes the Icon property and take the appropiate action.But since I'm developing something that will be used by different teams it's a "hard" requirement to force them to use my form as the base class, that's why I want it to work with a vanilla form (and overriding the WndProc the Win32 way seems like the only way to do it atm).

Comment: This is a symptom of a God class, a pretty troublesome design issue.  It is very unclear why you'd do anything at all when the Icon property is changed, it is a minor implementation detail for the title bar.  Get a good answer by explaining why it matters.

Comment: I'd like to manipulate the new icon. Under certain conditions I overlay an image to add some extra visual state information.

Comment: Like with most code it's not a matter of I need it or I loose my job, it's more that I'd like the user experience to be in a certain way (IMO optimal for my case).
The real problem is with the visible flag since the icon can be used even if the form is hidden (I enumerate all forms in a context menu).
When window is visible:
Form.Icon = NewIcon
Catch WM_SETICON, manipulate icon and set the to the manipulated.
Visible window is rendered with my manipulated icon.
Context menu is reading Form.Icon which is now manipulated and works ok.

Comment: With hidden window:
Form.Icon = NewIcon
(No WM_SETICON is called)
No window is visible so no problem here.
Context menu is reading from Form.Icon which isn't manipulated yet os it shows the wrong icon.
When form becomes visible, WM_SETICON is called and after that everything works ok.